# Url.Action generates wrong URL when Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Lots of similar questions and yet none quite like this problem:
I'm using attribute routing on an MVC5 project.
When trying to define a simple route like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Empresa/Filial/{id:int}/Editar")]
    public ActionResult UpdateFilial(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
```

and generate a URL on the view, like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UpdateFilial", "Empresa", new { id = filial.IDFilial })" title="@Lang.M("TitleEditar_Filial")" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">EDIT</a>
```

I end up with something like:

```
http://localhost:59936/Empresa/Filial/Editar?id=1
```

which results a 404, since it should be:

```
"http://localhost:59936/Empresa/Filial/1/Editar"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My RouteConfig looks like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Acionando rotas por atributos (annotations)
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

(the default on MVC5 template on VisualStudio2017)
So, I guess, attribute routing has precedence over convention based routes.

Comment: Have you enabled attribute routing in routeconfig.cs before convention-based routes?

Comment: There are a lot of different things that could be happening, but you haven't provided enough info in the question to determine the problem. 1) Is the `UpdateFilial` method in a controller named `EmpresaController`? 2) Are there any overloads of `UpdateFilial`? 3) Is the value of `filial.IDFilial` an int? One thing is certain - the call to `Url.Action` is not matching the route you have provided. And no, AttributeRouting doesn't take precedence over convention-based routes - routes are considered in the order they are registered. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that attribute routing has been enabled in `RouteConfig` before convention-based routes

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //enable attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //convention-based routes

        //...other routes

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```